# Dynamic Routing with .Net4 WCF Router Service

Tags: wcf-binding, wcf-client, wcf-routing

I'm looking for example for dynamic routing with .net 4 wcf service.
please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some resources that should help you get started:

[Hello World routing sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795218.aspx)

[Bridging and Error Handling routing sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667246.aspx)

[Advanced Filters routing sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667249.aspx)

[Dynamic routing sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667250.aspx)

[Advanced error handling routing sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667251.aspx)

[Routing topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx) -- full coverage of services, contracts, filters, and scenarios

[Routing Rules! Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/routingrules/) -- the entire blog is about the routing service and the different scenarios it enables. Take a read through all the blog posts for sure.

[Building a WCF Router, Part 1 on MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx)

[Building a WCF Router, Part 2 on MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx)